# Centos 7 - yum doesn't work

Tags: centos, python, yum

We have a server which is configured to update every 15 days. Ever since the recent update, we faced that yum is not able to update. This is the error when yum command is entered.

> There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
>   required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:
>
> No module named yum
>
> Please install a package which provides this module, or
>   verify that the module is installed correctly.
>
> It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
>   current version of Python, which is:
>   2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07)
>   [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]
>
> If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
>   the yum faq at:
>     http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq

Python --Version gives

> Python 2.7.5

hostnamectl gives

> Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
>
> CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
>
> Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64

Comment: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18383 this may help. You've broken your python install/yum install by upgrading python it seems.

Comment: Did it help? I am having exactly same problem, so wanted to know if any of the solution on this link fixed the issue or not ?